# changing background-image when scrolling

Tags: css, scroll

I was trying to change background-image while scrolling using only CSS3 but i failed. I need help how to do it on css3 only, not js.
I need to change background opacity of one image to zero and another to 1 having 5 breakpoints, while scrolling page. But i don't know how to process scrolling.
Will be thankful for help)

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It may be worth showing what you have tried so far so others can help you with the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
 var fromTopPx = 200; // distance to trigger
 var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
 if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
    jQuery('html').addClass('scrolled');
 }else{
    jQuery('html').removeClass('scrolled');``
 }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pZrCM/